# how does aiohttp handle onclick function

Tags: python, button, onclick, aiohttp

I am a newbie for the aiohttp, and I have a question below,

First, I have a button in the page as below,

```
<body>

<button class="button" name="click_me" onclick="click_me">Click Me</button>

</body>
```

and in the python code, I define the function as below,

```
async def click_me(request):
    logger.info(f'test on click_me')


async def handler(request):
    ... ... default code here ... ...
```

However, when I open the browser and click the "click_me" button, the debugging page shows the error,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: click_me is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

How to define the function in the python script to catch click_me event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [the `onclick` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#HTML_onevent_attributes) refers to a Javascript function, that must be loaded in your page. If you want to call a Python function from that click event, you must perform an HTTP request (or whatever, there are many other ways), for instance with [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), to your corresponing server's url. *e.g.*

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="doFoo()"></button>
  <script>
    async function doFoo() {
      const response = await fetch('http://YOURSERVER/foo')
      // do whatever you want with your response
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Will call the Python `foo` function defined here

```python
from aiohttp import web

async def foo(request):
    logger.info("button clicked")
    return web.Response()

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/foo', foo)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After I modified my code based on your suggestion, it works perfect. :-)